# More cells are being updated than the number of cells that exist in the table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm stumped by what seems to be a simple problem in my `Swift` iOS application.  What I'm trying to do is I'm displaying a list of 100 `cells` in a `tableview` where each `cell` says "Hello World".

Within `cellForRowAt:` I'm simulating a network call by implementing a sleep call for 2 seconds on the `background thread`.  Once that simulated network call is complete, I've updated the `table view cell` so that the text displays in bold.

I have 2 problems here:

1) The scrolling appears to be slightly choppy.  How do you fix this?

2) When I launch the app, if I `scroll` down REALLY quickly to the end of the list, I see that there is more than 100 cells updated (i.e. look at the print statement in `cellForRowAt`).  But if I scroll slowly from top to bottom, I see 100 `cells` updated.  Why is this happening?

Here is the main `ViewController.swift` file:

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variables
    private var cellsUpdated: Int = 0
    private let fontSize17: CGFloat = 17
    private let tableview: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()
    private var reuseIdentifier: String = "cell"
    private var sampleData = [TableData]()

    // MARK: - View Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        populateDataSet()
        setupTableView()
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Methods
    private func populateDataSet(){

        (0..<100).forEach { (_) in
            sampleData.append(TableData(value: "Hello World", hasBeenViewed: false))
        }
    }

    private func setupTableView(){

        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            tableview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            tableview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.sampleData[indexPath.row].value
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize17)
        if !self.sampleData[indexPath.row].hasBeenViewed {
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize17)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                // Simulate the execution of a CPU time intensive task on the background thread
                sleep(2)
                self.sampleData[indexPath.row].hasBeenViewed = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Update the table cells on the main thread
                    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: self.fontSize17)
                    self.cellsUpdated += 1
                    print("\(self.cellsUpdated) cells have been updated")
                }
            }
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize17)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return sampleData.count
    }
}
```

This file references a class called `TableData` which is just a simple class:

```
final class TableData {
    // MARK: - Internal Instance Variables
    var value: String
    var hasBeenViewed: Bool

    // MARK: - Init Method
    init(value: String, hasBeenViewed: Bool){
        self.value = value
        self.hasBeenViewed = hasBeenViewed
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you know more than 100 cells are updated? Why don't you print the `indexPath` along with the debug information of total count and check what is really happening?

Comment: Because the print statement shows that. Only happens when you scroll to the bottom fast.

Comment: Ok. So what extra rows are being updated?

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to figure out

Comment: Which is why i asked you to print the `indexPath` along with the count in the first comment...

Comment: @JFortYork  you don't need to add sleep for thread in your case . Whenever thread gets resources it will perform task . Also try to update cell data without any blocks.

Answer (score 2):

1- Scrolling isn't choppy tried it worked correctly

2- As you add this line here

```
sleep(2)
self.sampleData[indexPath.row].hasBeenViewed = true
```

while it should be here

```
if !self.sampleData[indexPath.row].hasBeenViewed {
   self.sampleData[indexPath.row].hasBeenViewed = true
```

As you delay assigning `hasBeenViewed = true` when you scroll back and forth for 1 item `if` triggers its called num of times > 1 so you see result > 100 unlike when you scroll slowly

Comment: I’ll try this and report back

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you!  Would you say that I've handled any possible race conditions and thread safety properly? It seems so to me.

Comment: So, more than 100 cells were updated because it was simply a timing issue?

Comment: Okay, thanks.  But back to the previous question.. is there any possible race conditions that I haven't handled? I'm sure it's thread safe since the background thread is handling the fake CPU task and then I'm updating the UI on the main thread.

Comment: yes after the task finishes the main thread part is executed if you have a request you can  also add the main block inside its callback

Answer (score 0):

You should not be handling network requests in that method, that is a bad design choice.

If you need to fetch data for each cell i would recommend you to create a `ViewModel` for the cell, make a `configure` method that takes a view model, inside the `Cell` class, in the viewModel, add the `fetch` or any intensive method you want to do.

Then it would look like this:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.configure(viewModel: sampleData[indexPath.row])
  return cell
}
```

By doing this you have much better separation of concerns, now you just need to focus on your heavy intensive task in the `ViewModel`, and remember to call `prepareForReuse()` in the cell to do cleanup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the assignment says to execute a "fake" network request everytime a cell appears in the table.  I think by dispatching the task to the background, it is handling it correctly given the scenario.

Comment: My suggestion does that, when you call the configure method with the view model, inside the configure method you need to call the view models method where you would dispatch the task

Comment: Oh... ok.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a code sample showing your UITableViewCell class? I just want to understand your solution better.  Do we need to make use of NSLock to make sure that there are no race conditions when updating the table view?